# InDesign: how to have editors collaborate on the content

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, workflow, collaboration

We're working on a magazine in Adobe InDesign. Is there a way to include the text content dynamically, so that a person who doesn't have InDesign can edit the text and the edits will automatically be reflected in the source file?

Answer (score 5):

If you use XML to import content, then it is possible to update the content if the manuscript changes. The XML shows up as a link in the palette and shows the yellow triangle if the file is changed, and can be managed just like art.

If you don't use XML for content, then Adobe does offer [InCopy](http://www.adobe.com/products/incopy/), which has the added benefit that the editor can see the text within the layout. We've looked into it from time to time, but the associated costs holds us back (not that XML is a cakewalk either).

Answer (score 1):

[InCopy](http://www.adobe.com/products/incopy/) immediately comes to mind, but you may also consider [DocsFlow or WordsFlow](http://emsoftware.com/products/wordsflow/) for dealing with shared text contents:

Answer (score 1):

You can write your text in any text editor in Markdown and use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to export it to InCopy ICML:

```
pandoc input.md -s -o output.icml
```

That ICML you can place in turn in InDesign. See [Importing Markdown in InDesign](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Importing-Markdown-in-InDesign) in the pandoc wiki for details.

Comment: This is a new one to me, but it looks excellent!